# Overriding data of local copy of database object, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, object, overriding

I want to be able to override the instance of a database object without affecting the original

Object @users = User.all with a table attribute :status

```
@users[0].status = nil
```

Causes the status attribute to equal to nil when I read it with @users[0].status

However, when I do:

```
@users.find(1).status = nil
```

Does not change the status, notably a sql query is called when I use the find command, as such it is the database data that I am receiving 
I tried using the .dup and .clone methods

```
@users=User.all.dup
```

Did not work

How do I go about with this? Do I have to create a temporary table? I am using postgres

Comment: What is the actual problem that  your are trying to solve? This sounds very much like an X & Y problem.

Comment: So I have a table users that have their schedule on it. When my system calculates a user's availability for the next week it will cross check the vacation days table first. Since vacation days only occur once, if I update the user table based on vacation days I will have to reset the table contents once I have calculated a users availability. So It goes user's schedule -> check for vacation days and alter user schedule-> check for availability for the week -> reset user table. If I can modify a copy of the user table I would not have to reset the user table